# Setting the row height of a Kendo grid control?

Tags: kendo-grid

Simple enough right?  I just need to know the syntax to do this when the grid is defined in the .html.  Using this example, where would it go?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        groupable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name"
        },
        {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name"
        }],
        dataSource: {
            data: [{
                FirstName: "Joe",
                LastName: "Smith"
            },
            {
                FirstName: "Jane",
                LastName: "Smith"
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the row height using CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the height property for the tr in the grid using the following style

```
 .k-grid tbody tr{
    height: 50px;
}
```

[Refer here for a live demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ECUja)

Comment: What if we eant to set a fixed height? So the row's height not grow when has a long text??